# My first finished Python program: a deck of cards

Tags: python, beginner, object-oriented, python-3.x, playing-cards

I've recently started learning how to code in Python, and have even more recently learned the basics of object-oriented programming. Feeling inspired, I started on a program that would generate random cards.  I'm really excited to have completed a project like this for the first time!

I had a problem of duplicates, which was quickly solved by @user2357112 when they suggested I create a deck list.

After that, it was smooth sailing. Being a relatively new programmer though, I thought I'd get some suggestions for making the code more Pythonic, decreasing any repetition (which I kept minimal), using easier methods to do the same thing, etc.

I will also take any suggestions on code organization; being largely self-taught, my code may not be laid-out neatly as it could be.

```
# This program is practice for using classes, and doubles as a useful card deck program. Hopefully this can be of some use.
# Made by [brilliantlyInsane].

from random import randint as rand
from random import shuffle

suits = ("Spades","Hearts","Clubs","Diamonds")

class Card:
    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        if rank not in range(1, 14):
            raise TypeError('Rank must be an integer between 1 and 13.')
        if suit not in suits:
            raise TypeError('Suit must be a string: "Spades", "Hearts", "Clubs", or "Diamonds".')
        # The quick check above makes sure the card being made actually exists in a standard deck of 52.
        # If so, the card is created succesfully.
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit


    def cardName(self):
        """
        Returns a string containing the card's name in common terms.
        """
        if self.rank == 1:
            trueRank = "Ace"
        elif self.rank == 11:
            trueRank = "Jack"
        elif self.rank == 12:
            trueRank = "Queen"
        elif self.rank == 13:
            trueRank = "King"
        else:
            trueRank = str(self.rank)
        return "{rank} of {suit}".format(rank = trueRank, suit = self.suit)

    def flip(self):
        """
        Reveals the requested card.
        """
        print(self.cardName())

def newDeck():
    """
    Resets the deck to ascending order, containing all 52 cards.
    """
    global cardDeck
    cardDeck = [Card(rank, suit) for suit in suits for rank in range(1, 14)]
    cardDeck.reverse() # So that the bottom of the list is the top of the deck, i.e. the Ace of Spades is drawn first by 'cardDeck.pop()'.

newDeck()   # To generate the deck at the start. Note that it is not shuffled at first.

def shuffleDeck():
    """
    Self-explanatory. Shuffles the deck.
    """
    global cardDeck
    for i in range(0, 3):
        shuffle(cardDeck)   # Python's pseudorandom generator is slightly patterned unless shuffled multiple times.

def draw():
    """
    Draws a single card to a variable.
    Useful for replacing and discarding individual cards in a hand, such as replacing cards in poker.
    To do so: <hand>[<card to replace>] = cards.draw()
    Remember that the list for a hand starts from 0, not 1.
    """
    randCard = cardDeck.pop()
    return randCard

def drawFaceUp():
    randCard = cardDeck.pop()
    randCard.flip()
    return randCard

def drawHand(size):
    """
    Draws a <size>-card hand from the deck.
    """
    return [draw() for i in range(0, size)]

def showHand(hand):
    size = len(hand)
    for i in range(0, size):
        hand[i].flip()

def newCard():
    """
    Generates a random card outside of the established deck, and prints its value.
    While occasionally useful, using newCard() for hands is discouraged. Duplicates of preexisting cards will result.
    """
    suit = suits[rand(0, 3)]
    rank = rand(1,13)
    randCard = Card(rank,suit)
    print("The {card} has been generated.".format(card = str(randCard.cardName())))
    return randCard

def cardHelp():
    """
    Gives a set of instructions explaining the use of the 'cards.py' module.
    """
    print('\n' + '=' * 72)
    print('=' * 13 + " [brilliantlyInsane]'s Python Cards: Instructions " + '=' * 14)
    print('=' * 72 + '\n')

    print('—' * 16 + " The Cards " + '—' * 45)
    print('—' * 72)
    print('The "Card" object has two attributes:')
    print('rank - An integer between 1 and 13. (Ace = 1, Jack = 11, Queen = 12, King = 13.)')
    print('suit - A string value of either "Spades", "Hearts", "Clubs", or "Diamonds".')
    print('A specific card object can be made: "Card(<rank>,<suit>)".\n')

    print('—' * 16 + " Drawing Cards " + '—' * 41)
    print('—' * 72)
    print('"Draw" cards to a variable with "<var> = cards.draw()".')
    print('Use "cards.drawFaceUp() to draw a card and print its value.')
    print('"Flip" a card (print its value) with "<var>.flip()".')
    print('Generate an entirely new random card using "cards.newCard()".')
    print('(Note that "newCard()" duplicates a card in the deck.)\n')

    print('—' * 16 + " Hands " + '—' * 49)
    print('—' * 72)
    print('To draw an entire hand with <size> many cards, use "cards.drawHand(<size>)".')
    print('To show a hand, use "cards.showHand(<hand>)."\n')

    print('—' * 16 + " Replacing Cards " + '—' * 39)
    print('—' * 72)
    print('You can replace individual cards in a hand using <hand>[card #] = cards.draw().')
    print('However, lists in Python start FROM 0, not 1!')
    print('"hand[1] = cards.draw()" will replace the SECOND card in your hand, not the first!\n')

    print('—' * 16 + " The Deck " + '—' * 46)
    print('—' * 72)
    print('The deck is stored to a list under the variable "cards.cardDeck".')
    print('Shuffle using "shuffleDeck()". The deck is unshuffled by default.')
    print('Reset the deck completely using cards.newDeck().')
    print('\n' + '=' * 72 + '\n')

print('Type "cards.cardHelp()" to learn how to use this module.')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some comments:

#### Check out PEP8

[PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is like the style guide of Python. You don't need to adhere to it, but most people are used to reading code that does.

#### Avoid global variables

Like @RUser4512 mentioned, go OOP, thus avoiding global variables.

Your code will look like this:

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self, rank, suit): pass
    def name(self): pass
    def flip(self): pass

class Deck:
    def __init__(self): pass  # newDeck()
    def shuffle(self): pass
    def draw(self): pass
    def draw_hand(self, size): pass
    def draw_faceup(self): pass

def show_help(): pass
```

#### Using idioms like __str__()

You might want to change `name()` to `__str__()`. Then you can use `str(card)` to get the name. If I were you, unless you plan to implement additional behaviour for `flip()`, I would just avoid it and use `print(card)` to print the card info.

#### Don't print text on module load

Avoid printing anything when someone imports your module. The users of your library might not appreciate this. Instead, use a docstring at the start of your module.

#### If you do want to write a function to print the help, use functions

```
print('—' * 16 + " Hands " + '—' * 49)
print('—' * 72)
```

is more readable -- and easier for you to write ;) -- when replaced by

```
def print_line(text=None):
    if text:
        output = '-' * 16 + " {} ".format(text)
        output = output.ljust(72, "-")
    else:
        output = "-" * 72
    print(output)

print_line("Hands")
print_line()
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not a Python expert but I have some comments.

The case style. Most Python users prefer using underscores instead of upper case letters. See : [What is the naming convention in Python for variable and function names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159720/what-is-the-naming-convention-in-python-for-variable-and-function-names)

**Global variables:**

```
def newDeck():
    """
    Resets the deck to ascending order, containing all 52 cards.
    """
    global cardDeck
    cardDeck = [Card(rank, suit) for suit in suits for rank in range(1, 14)]
    cardDeck.reverse() # So that the bottom of the list is the top of the deck, i.e. the Ace of Spades is drawn first by 'cardDeck.pop()'.
```

Do you need a `global` variable ? Can't you just put the deck you draw the card from in the argument of the `drawCardFromDeck` function ?

You could change the other method, like

```
def drawCardFromDeck(cardDeck):
    """
    Draws a single card to a variable.
    Useful for replacing and discarding individual cards in a hand, such as replacing cards in poker.
    To do so: <hand>[<card to replace>] = cards.draw()
    Remember that the list for a hand starts from 0, not 1.
    """
    return cardDeck.pop()
```

To emphasize the fact that `cardDeck` is modified when this method is called.

**Go OOP**

But there is another problem with the `global` deck. What happens if you want to have another deck (for some reason). All these would be even better if `Deck` was itself a class with methods:

1. `__init__` your current `newDeck()`
2. `draw()`, `drawHand(size)`, `drawFaceUp()`, `shuffleDeck()` would be method from this deck class and it would be more legitimate for them to change the state of the deck.

Comment: `drawCardFormDeck()` [sic] should just return `randCard`.  `cardDeck` is mutated, so there is no need to return it. Returning a tuple just makes the function hard to use.

Comment: @200_success, you are right, fixed !

Comment: You might as well drop `randCard` altogether and just `return cardDeck.pop()`.

Comment: @200_success edited as well

Answer (score 1):

```
def cardName(self):
        """
        Returns a string containing the card's name in common terms.
        """
        if self.rank == 1:
            trueRank = "Ace"
        elif self.rank == 11:
            trueRank = "Jack"
        elif self.rank == 12:
            trueRank = "Queen"
        elif self.rank == 13:
            trueRank = "King"
        else:
            trueRank = str(self.rank)
        return "{rank} of {suit}".format(rank = trueRank, suit = self.suit)
```

This can be shortened, simplified (and made more pythonic):

```
specialCards = {11: "Jack", 12: "Queen", 13:"King", 1: "Ace"}

def generateCardName(self):
  name = specialCards[self.rank] if rank in specialCards else rank
  return '%s of %s'(name, self.suit)
```

But like someone said above, go OOP.

So I would have

```
class Card:
  def __init__(self, rank, suit):
    self.rank = rank
    self.suit = suit


  def cardName(self):
    specialCards = {11: "Jack", 12: "Queen", 13:"King", 1: "Ace"}
    rank_name = specialCards[self.rank] if self.rank in specialCards else self.rank
    return '%s of %s'%(rank_name, self.suit)
```

Instantiate it like this:

```
my_card = Card(1,"Spades")
print my_card.cardName()
```

For the whole card deck:

```
suits = ["Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"]
cards = [Card(rank, suit) for rank in range(1,14) for suit in suits]
```