# Using enums in a card/deck class

Tags: python, object-oriented, python-3.x, enum

I recognize that this is a common question area with lots of answers:
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42801071/creating-a-playing-card-class-python) and [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/121861/my-first-finished-python-program-a-deck-of-cards) for example.

Specifically I'm trying to better understand how to use Enums in Python. Suits in a deck of cards seems appropriate, but implementing them as a class seems extra, and I'm curious if there's a more pythonic way to do it?

```
class Suits(Enum):
    Club = 1
    Heart = 2
    Diamond = 3
    Spade = 4

class Card:
    def __init__(self, value, suit):
        self.value = value
        self.suit = suit

class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = self.initDeck()

    def initDeck():
        cards = {}
        for suit in Suits:
            for i in range(14):
                cards.add(Card(i, suit))
        return cards
```

The whole point of Enums is to prevent you from adding a bad value though, right? (Like, making a new card as `Card(0, 'joker')`) so maybe this isn't the right application for it? Currently there would be no error if I passed `Card(4, 'dimond')` and that's exactly what enums are supposed to prevent, right?

Hoping for a bit more insight/education. Thanks!

Comment: That is one of the reasons for enums yes so I do think it is appropriate. As for a joker card - I think it is better to have a base class (e.g. Card, abstract if Python supports it), then two sub classes - JokerCard and SuitCard. That way you don't have to specify rank or suit for JokerCards. Also - strongly suggest avoiding magic numbers like "14".

Comment: For the record, I didn't vote to close because it was unclear what you asked. It's perfectly clear. However, it's example code instead of a review of actual code in actual context. It smells like one of those [best practices in general](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) questions which shouldn't be asked here.

Comment: @Mast that's fair, this IS a best practices in general/"how do I use Enums" question. I asked it over in SO and was directed here. So worries on the vote to close

Comment: @Acoustic77 Unfortunately there's plenty of people on SO redirecting unsuspecting users here without having a clue what Code Review is about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation uses `Enum` for the suits, but not for the values.  Thus it is harder to validate the card values, and would as you noted, allow a *joker* card to be created, even though you didn't want that ability.

#### Card Value Enum:

A card value `enum` provides the ability to give the cards a value and a descriptive name, while limiting possible values to valid ranges:

```
class CardValue(Enum):
    Ace = 1
    Deuce = 2
    Three = 3
    Four = 4
    Five = 5
    Six = 6
    Seven = 7
    Eight = 8
    Nine = 9
    Ten = 10
    Jack = 11
    Queen = 12
    King = 13
```

#### Immutable Types

For something like a card, an immutable type can provide some advantages.  One big one, is that the same value and suit will always key the same in a set or dict. Inheriting from tuple will achieve imuutability.  Note that the class is setup in `__new__` not `__init__` since it is immutable.

```
class Card(tuple):

    def __new__(cls, value, suit):
        assert isinstance(value, CardValue)
        assert isinstance(suit, CardSuit)
        return tuple.__new__(cls, (value, suit))
```

#### property decorator

The property decorator makes it easy to access the `value` and `suit`.

```
    @property
    def value(self):
        return self[0]

    @property
    def suit(self):
        return self[1]
```

#### `__str__` method

Since we are using `Enum`'s for all of the values, a fully descriptive `__str__` method is quite straight forward:

```
    def __str__(self):
        return "{} of {}s".format(self.value.name, self.suit.name)
```

So something like:

```
print(Card(CardValue.Ace, CardSuit.Club))
```

gives:

```
Ace of Clubs
```

#### Make sure we stay immutable

Suggest adding some boilerplate to help avoid abusing the class instances.

```
    def __setattr__(self, *ignored):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def __delattr__(self, *ignored):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

#### Deck class

So the `Deck` class can be made much simpler with the new `Value` class and a `set` comprehension like:

```
class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = {
            Card(value, suit) for value in CardValue for suit in CardSuit
        }
```

#### Whole Listing:

```
from enum import Enum

class CardValue(Enum):
    Ace = 1
    Deuce = 2
    Three = 3
    Four = 4
    Five = 5
    Six = 6
    Seven = 7
    Eight = 8
    Nine = 9
    Ten = 10
    Jack = 11
    Queen = 12
    King = 13


class CardSuit(Enum):
    Club = 1
    Heart = 2
    Diamond = 3
    Spade = 4


class Card(tuple):

    def __new__(cls, value, suit):
        assert isinstance(value, CardValue)
        assert isinstance(suit, CardSuit)
        return tuple.__new__(cls, (value, suit))

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self[0]

    @property
    def suit(self):
        return self[1]

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} of {}s".format(self.value.name, self.suit.name)

    def __setattr__(self, *ignored):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def __delattr__(self, *ignored):
        raise NotImplementedError

class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = {
            Card(value, suit) for value in CardValue for suit in CardSuit
        }
```